# PUT/POST request in SOAPUI giving 403 forbidden, while same request working fine in rest client Postman

Tags: api, rest, testing, soapui

There is no authentication on server side so authentication should not be issue.

URL format: PUT
 https://localhost/api/v1/protections?integrationKey=111&userKey=1111&group=111&category=foo

Payload:
{"action":"BLOCK"}

This is working fine in Postman.
In SOAP UI , I am giving input as under:
EndPoint: https://localhost
Resource: /api/v1/protections
Parameters:?integrationKey=111&userKey=1111&group=111&category=foo

in Media type, I am selecting "application/json"
and entering  {"action": "BLOCK"} but getting "Wed Jan 20 16:25:27 PST 2016:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
"
Is there any suggestion to get the output in SOAP UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server where the rest is exposed service generates an HTTP 403, you should verify that server is and thus find the fastest response.
Also try making a GET request from the browser to see if you can answer correctly because problem lock your machine to the server.

Comment: Thanks ToKpelto for comment, GET is working fine from SOAPUI and POSTMAN . that makes me more confuse, I checked each and every parameter I am giving in both. They are same. Don't know what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

As is https, it may be that you lack some certificate set SOAPUI. possibly Postman you use already has configured. Try to check this setting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I missed the Header "User-Agent" and "accept". I put in Soap UI and Works.
In Postman, this headers it put automatically.

[image]